# Retrieve Id of object being passed from call function

Tags: javascript, object, methods, meteor

Is there a way to retrieve the Id of the object being passed in from a call function. I have inserted the object into a collection in the method, so this is fine. But, I also want to retrieve this object's Id and insert it into the current users profile.postcreated field.

My call function:

```
Template.createpost.events({
'submit form#createpost': function(e, tmpl) {
e.preventDefault();
var insertpost = {
field: $( "#someId" ).val();
}
Meteor.call('insertPostData', insertpost);
} });
```

Method function:

```
Meteor.methods({
'insertPostData': function(insertPostData){
  return AllPosts.insert(insertPostData);  //THIS WORKS FINE
  Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $addToSet: { 'profile.postcreated': **objectsId** }}
);
});
```

Comment: Can't you just pass it via the insertpost object you are creating? failing that, only pass the field instead of it's value, that way you can access it's value, attributes and even manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection.insert` returns the inserted object `_id`, so you just need to store it in a variable for later use.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insertPostData': function(insertPostData){
    var user=Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    // assuming postcreated is something like ["POSTID"]
    if(user.profile.postcreated.length>=1){
      return;
    }
    var postId=AllPosts.insert(insertPostData);
    Meteor.users.update(this.userId,{
      $addToSet:{
        'profile.postcreated':postId
      }
    });
    return postId;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect saimeunt!

Comment: How can I prevent this insert if the postcreated field is already populated? Is the following code close? ...
 if (this.userId().profile.postcreated.find().count() < 1){..insertion code}

Comment: Edited my answer, this is how I would do it.

Comment: The inclusion of this particular if statement is not allowing the insertion at all.

Comment: Please edit your question with info regarding this `postcreated` field (what it represents, how it is populated, etc...) because it's difficult to answer if I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: The postcreated field holds all ids of the posts created by the user. The insertPostData actually has many fields like 'title' 'message' and is stored into the AllPosts collection. I would like to store this post id into 'postcreated' field within the users profile. This was achieved earlier. But I just want to limit the user only being able to create one post.

Comment: If the postcreated field is an array, you have to test against its length property, and abort insertion if it's greater or equal to 1. You have to take care of proper initialization of the postcreated property to an empty array on user creation too.

Comment: Thanks. It is an array. How can I initialise it to store as element. Changing postcreated: [] to postcreated: {} upon creating user profile? I'll reference mongodb manual.